# What is the best way to embed this event handler function to use within a Kotlin coroutine?

Tags: kotlin, telegram-bot, kotlin-coroutines

I'm currently trying to add a coroutine flow, to control timeout,... and enable easy multithreading.

The following solution is not really working.

```kotlin
    // import from `com.elbekD.bot`
    public fun onCommand(command: String, action: suspend (Message, String?) -> Unit)
```

I'm using this TelegramBot library https://github.com/elbekD/kt-telegram-bot.

```kotlin
 fun startBotCommandFlow(action: (params: String?) -> Unit) {
        val timeout = 600000L
        val smsFlow: Flow<String> = flow {
            bot.onCommand(command = "/test", action = { _, opts ->
                withContext(NonCancellable) {
                    when {
                        !opts.isNullOrEmpty() -> {
                            sendMessage("I'll apply your text!")
                            emit(opts)
                        }
                        else -> {
                            sendMessage("Non or invalid text received! Pls retry")
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }


       GlobalScope.launch {
            bot.start()
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                try {
                    // setup 10 min timeout
                    withTimeout(timeout) {
                        sendMessage("Please paste your TEXT (\"/test\")")
                        smsFlow.collect { value ->
                            println("Received $value")
                            action(value)
                        }
                    }
                } catch (ex: TimeoutCancellationException) {
                    val errorMsg = "Chance is expired!"
                    sendMessage(errorMsg)
                    log.error(errorMsg)
                    this.cancel(errorMsg)
                } finally {
                    this.cancel()
                }
            }
        }.invokeOnCompletion {
            bot.close()
        }
  }
```

I also found some other issues which could be solved by `callbackFlow` or `channelFlow`.
But I'm not sure how to apply this in a correct way.

And if I run the action without a `flow`, the coroutine will complete immediately.

```kotlin
withTimeout(timeout) {
  sendMessage("Please paste your TEXT (\"/test\")")
  bot.chain("/test") {
    testAction(it.text, action)
  }.build()
  log.debug("Listener activated")
}
```

Do you have any idea how I can fix my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you need `callbackFlow`, not `flow`.  What's unclear about how to use them?

Comment: @LouisWasserman How should I close the callbackFlow, without exception?

Comment: is it okay to use `testCallbackFlow.collect {delay(timeout)}` to keep the stream open?

Comment: No.  You shouldn't have to do anything to keep the stream open.  Use `awaitClose`.